# Can a laptop hard drive be used in a desktop computer?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, hardware-rec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install a laptop 2.5" SATA drive on a desktop without any adapters?](https://superuser.com/questions/2086/can-i-install-a-laptop-2-5-sata-drive-on-a-desktop-without-any-adapters)

The drive is:

> Kingston SSDNow V+200 SVP200S3 / 240G 2.5" 240GB SATA III Internal Solid State Drive (SSD) (Stand-alone Drive)

Can I use this drive in my desktop computer?

Comment: You can also use an adapter or enclosure to make it into an external (USB) drive that can be used with most things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a laptop hard drive can be used in a desktop computer.

You need to buy a [Hard Drive Adapter](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=de&sclient=psy-ab&q=2.5%20to%203.5%20hard%20drive%20adapter) that allows you to build your 2.5 hard drive into your desktop tower. And possibly you'll need a SATA III cable. Make sure one of your hard drive bays is free, too.

If your computer is fairly recent, you will probably need just a SATA cable. If it is older and sports an IDE, you'll also need an [adapter from SATA to IDE](https://www.google.com/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=sata%20to%20IDE%20adapter)

Comment: Apparently SATA drives use the same cabling, while IDE needs an adapter.

Comment: I perhaps wouldn't call it an adapter, but more a modified drive bay.

Comment: I think adapter is a common term for this kind of contraption and it would show up useful results in a Google search.

Comment: That works too :) I recommend adding in your answer that an appropriate drive bay will be needed to secure the drive properly.

Comment: like this (see above)?

Comment: Well most desktops only have 3.5 and 5.5 drive backs. Laptops will be a 2.5.